# How to integrate validation in AngularJS with poshytip

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I don't want a mere class style using `ng-class`. What I want is to show tooltip using some Jquery plugin (poshy tip plugin) in this case.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You would have to create a angular directive that applies the poshytip plugin over the element on which you want the tooltip.

Comment: Hi Chandu, thanks. But how do I know if the control is valid or not inside directive?